# Summernote cannot put data laravel

Tags: php, laravel, summernote

I can save data using summernote editor, but when my textarea using class summernote it can not put that data. You can see my form edit.blade :

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'put', 'id' => 'form-admin', 'action'=>array('AdminController@update', 'id'), 'files' => true)) !!}
 <div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::label('Deskripsi : ')!!}
    {!!Form::textarea('deskripsi',null,['id'=>'deskripsi','class'=>'form-control summernote','placeholder'=>'Deskripsi'])!!}
 </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

[image]

but when I tried to put the data not using class summernote it can put the data.

```
{!!Form::textarea('deskripsi',null,['id'=>'deskripsi','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Deskripsi'])!!}
```

[image]

this is my script edit :

```
function EditModal(btn){
    var route = "http://localhost:8000/admin/"+btn.value+"/edit";

    $.get(route, function(res){
       $("#deskripsi").val(res.deskripsi);
       $("#form-admin").attr("action", "http://localhost:8000/admin/" + btn.value);
    });
}
```

can you help me ? I can create data using summernote but when I edit, I can put that data.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE EXAMPLE**

I'm seen your uploaded file, and your code is too mess :)
So if you want to make a comparasion your code with the working one you can try this, just copy paste this http://pastebin.com/Yd812rq0 code in your view file to see this code is work.

This is proven by myself (i simplify the code for you to read this easier)

[image: view]
[image: code]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

you cannot use val() in this case.

refer to the documentation http://summernote.org/getting-started/#basic-api
this is the way you must to do to set your data / text into summernote textarea

```
var markupStr = 'hello world';
$('#summernote').summernote('code', markupStr);
```

That's mean your code should be like this :

```
function EditModal(btn){
    var route = "http://localhost:8000/admin/"+btn.value+"/edit";

    $.get(route, function(res){
        $("#deskripsi").summernote('code', res.deskripsi);
        $("#form-admin").attr("action", "http://localhost:8000/admin/" + btn.value);
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried `$('#summernote').summernote('code', 'my text here');` this code and had no problem, i think you had other problems. Can you run this code  `alert('res.deskripsi')` and what the output ?

Comment: When i run alert('res.deskripsi') it show my data deskripsi.

Comment: i have tried `$("#summernote").summernote('code','testing tes');` it not show my text "testing tes" . you know what my problem ?

Comment: No, you must use `$("#deskripsi").summernote('code','testing tes');` because your `textarea` id is `deskripsi`.

anyway, can you upload your entire `.blade` file ? so i'll know what's your actual problem.

Comment: Hi, why i cannot find `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.7.0/summernote.js` this script in your code ?

Comment: sorry i forget to upload my layout/admin.blade but i sure to add summernote plugin. i think before put the data its must to decode character or before upload the data its must decode, the example when we want save <div> in the database must be "%3Cdiv%3E" .
btw, you can see my layout/admin.blade :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u92sx9payd2aj3p/admin.blade.php?dl=0

Comment: It's looks like order problem, your script run before you call `summernote.js`.

Call it like this in your `index.blade.php` `@section('scripts') {!!Html::script('js/scriptModal2.js')!!} @stop`